# Any semblance of originally-requested domain name in HTTP, post DNS-resolution?

Tags: domain-name-system, proxy, http

My *understanding* of how DNS resolution and web browsers work is as follows:

1. Your browser uses the DNS system that ultimately connects it to your registrars name servers
2. Your registrar's name servers then, ultimately, send the mapped IP address back to your browser
3. Your browser then makes a direct HTTP connection to the IP address returned by the registrar's name server

If anything I have said so far is inaccurate or mislead, or is omitting any major components, *please* begin by correcting me!

Assuming my understanding of DNS resolution and IP address lookups is more or less on track, then I have the following question:

After the browser has resolved a domain name to an IP address (via DNS), it makes a direct HTTP connection to that IP address.  **When doing so, is there any reference *whatsoever* of the originally-requested URL?**

In other words, say `blah.example.com` gets resolved to an IPv4 address of `1.2.3.4`. A request to `http://blah.example.com/fizz` would then get translated to a request to `http://1.2.3.4:80/fizz`. My question is: **in this 2nd request (which references the IP address directly), are there any headers/metadata referencing `blah.example.com`?**

I looked at [Wikipedia's list of standard HTTP request headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields), and much to my dismay, couldn't find any that stood out. I guess I was sort of hoping for a header like `Requested-URL`, etc.

There has to be *some* way of tying the 2nd HTTP request to the originally requested name, otherwise I don't think proxies or load balancers could ever work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's in the Host header:

```
curl -v http://www.google.ca/ >/dev/null
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 2607:f8b0:400c:c03::5e...
* Connected to www.google.ca (2607:f8b0:400c:c03::5e) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: www.google.ca
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 03 Nov 2014 15:31:59 GMT
< Expires: -1
< Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
< Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=eb76c9020ebd6a26:FF=0:TM=1415028719:LM=1415028719:S=pxxk1qaEXquTWjHO; expires=Wed, 02-Nov-2016 15:31:59 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.ca
< Set-Cookie: NID=67=bzNq9pQagemSuByTb3SUrkchTiOk9KshhQuO4qyTcjH-Z5lo92jfP9bfpW8twUDan65AslDGV1DyWnjJ2C17BqDVUQ6OGrq2BG3WFcGbCJladFmS0WAxEr7CinTF_I5S; expires=Tue, 05-May-2015 15:31:59 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.ca; HttpOnly
< P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
* Server gws is not blacklisted
< Server: gws
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,p=0.01
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
{ [data not shown]
100 17846    0 17846    0     0  92164      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 92466
* Connection #0 to host www.google.ca left intact
```

Comment: Also note that you can construct the URL by combining the hostname with what got passed in to the GET... e.g. for @smeeb's example of http://blah.example.com/fizz, you would see a GET /fizz HTTP/1.1

Comment: Note that the Host header was optional in HTTP 1.0, so may not always be present

Comment: @Greg True, but anything _that_ ancient should no longer be on the Internet; it wouldn't be able to access many websites anyway.